# mongodb java driver readFully is slow

Tags: mongodb

db.collection.find in my app that uses mongodb java driver (latest) are super slow. I investigated one of them as follows

```
// about 300 hundred ids at a time (i've tried lower and higher numbers - no impact
db.users.find({_id : {$in : [1,2,3,4,5,6....]}})
```

Once I get the cursor I do: `cursor.toArray()` and then iterate of the results

The toArray operation is extremely slow. On average they take about a minute. IMPORTANT: my database is under very heavy load at all times. This particular collection has over 50mm entries.

I've narrowed down the issue in mongo java driver to com.mongodb.Response - specifically to this line:

```
 final byte [] b = new byte[36];
 Bits.readFully(in, b);
```

Incredibly readFully of just 36 bytes takes over a minute some times!

When I bring own the load on the databases, the improvements are drastic. From about a minute to 5-6 seconds. I mean 5-6 seconds to get 300 documents is still super slow, but definitely better then 1 minute.

What can I do to troubleshoot this further? Are there settings on MondoDB that I need to look at?

Comment: Why are you calling `cursor.toArray()` only to iterate over the results? The cursor is designed to be iterated over more efficiently than having to store all of the results in memory in an array before iterating.

Comment: In this situation I needed all results (keep in my mind I specifically requesting 300 entries). I looked at the mongo java driver and it looks like toArray is still performing all typical cursor operation. So using cursor.hasNext,next and calling toArray is the same thing.

Comment: OK, so you want to get 300 results, put them in an array, and do something with it? Your current code gets ALL documents, one batch at a time, not 300 total. Try `db.users.find(...).limit(300)` to return a cursor that returns at most 300 documents. If you want to process 300 at a time, then the next 300, then the next, etc, sort on `_id`, remember the last `_id`, and use it to form the next query: `db.users.find({..., "_id" : { "$gt" : <last _id of prev results> } })).limit(300).sort({ "_id" : 1 })`

Answer (score 0):

#### What happens

You are loading all of the 300 user documents.

What happens is that the `_id` index is searched and the respective documents are sent completely to your app. So mongoDB will access it's data files, read the first document and send it to you, then it jumps to the next document and sends it to you and so forth. If you used the cursor, you could start iterating over the returned documents as soon as a number of documents equalling your defined cursor size have been returned, as others will be lazily loaded from the cursor on the server on demand. (Bit of a simplification, but sufficient for answering this question). What you do is to explicitly wait until the index is scanned, the documents are located, sent back to your app and have reached it down to the last byte of the last document. As @wdberkeley (who works for 10gen) correctly pointed out, this is a Very Bad Idea™.

#### What might cause or intensify the problem

Under heavy load, two things might happen. The more likely is that your `_id` index isn't in RAM any more, causing thousands, if not millions of reads from disk - which is *slow*. Much slower than if the indices are kept in RAM (by *several* orders of magnitude). So it is not the code snippet you mentioned, but the response time of MongoDB which causes the delay. Another option under heavy load is that your disk IO is simply too low or (more likely) the random file read latency is too high. I assume you are using spinning disks plus not enough RAM for a database that size.

#### What to do to find the cause

1. Try to find out your index size using the `db.users.stats()`. I am pretty sure that your index size(s combined) exceed your available RAM.
2. Measure the disk IO and latency. If you use a GNU/Linux OS, you might want to find out how high your IOwait percentage is. A high percentage shows that your disk latency is too high for the load put on the server. It might even be that your are reaching the disk's IO limits.
3. Do your queries on a mongo shell. In case they are fast, you can be pretty sure that your toArray call is the cause of the problem.

#### What to do to resolve the problem

If you have not enough RAM, either scale up or scale out.

If your disk latency or throughput is too high, either scale out or ( better and cheaper in most cases ) use SSDs for storing MongoDB's data.

Use a cursor object to iterate over the documents. This is a better solution in almost every use case I can think of.

Comment: Ok - to confirm, my RAM must be GREATER THEN total index size for the entire database? While my db.users.stats().totalIndexSize is 2GB and my total RAM is 12GB, my db.stats().indexSize is 16GB. Is this my problem?

Comment: Also about - using cursor to toArray - I tried both and found to difference between them. I look at java driver code and to me it seemed like it was basically doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

**Upgrading MongoDB driver to 3.6.4 will fetch the data in no-time.**
 We have around 2 million documents in our collection and with previous version it was taking around ~3 minutes but after after upgrading to 3.6.4 it took only 5-7 sec.So what I feel is that there is some issue with the old version of mongoDB driver.